# Dpdk Virtio Vring Negotiation Abnormal

Tags: dpdk

I have an process1 with EAL param like :  `--vdev"/tmp/socket",queues=4,server=1` as virtio front-end and another process2 as back-end.

when they finish negotiation, nothing in dpdk's log wrong, but when I print each queue's situation, it shows below:

```
Queue idx: 0,  pkt in queue: 0; 
Queue idx: 1,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 2,  pkts in queue: 0; 
Queue idx: 3,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 4,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 5,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 6,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 7,  pkts in queue: 256;
```

The capacity of queue 4 and 6 supposed to be 0 but it is 256, I am sure the back-end process has not start to process pkt yet.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I find the answer myself.

I try to find the question by using testpmd, When I use the same EAL param, the log shows:

```
Queue idx: 0,  pkt in queue: 0; 
Queue idx: 1,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 2,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 3,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 4,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 5,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 6,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 7,  pkts in queue: 256;
```

I guess it's port not config, and it just use 1 queue. I config port using `port config all rxq 4` to config port to use 4 rx queues, and then the log shows:

```
Queue idx: 0,  pkt in queue: 0; 
Queue idx: 1,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 2,  pkts in queue: 0; 
Queue idx: 3,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 4,  pkts in queue: 0; 
Queue idx: 5,  pkts in queue: 256; 
Queue idx: 6,  pkts in queue: 0; 
Queue idx: 7,  pkts in queue: 256;
```